# No connection to webserver over local network.

Tags: networking, webserver, local

I have set up a webserver on a Fedora 20 computer, which I can access in the browser on that computer. When I go to the ip address of the Fedora computer in a web browser of another computer on the local network, there is no connection. What do I have to do to access the server?

Answer (score 0):

Many times, the instructions for setting up a web server for local web development have you set the web server software to only bind to the 127.0.0.1 loopback address, so that it is only accessible from the local host. To fix this, you need to tell your web server software package to bind to all addresses (or at least to bind to the IP address you have on the network interface you care about). Unfortunately, the instructions for how to do this can vary greatly from one web server software package to another, so you'll have to either figure it out for yourself or tell us which web server software package you're running (Apache? nginx? lighttpd? WEBrick? etc.).

Comment: @splif the thing is i have installed Zenoss server in my system when i run it on my local server it is running but when i am trying to access it from other system it is not working so i thought that he is also getting the same things but after you'r comment i figured it out that ssh will enable access to secure shell and snmpd will enable sending the ICMP packets to the server . But both here is not used for communicating to https.